# Bind DataTable to TreeView without Iterations

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, datatable, treeview

I'm able to Bind the Datatable Column to Gridview

Here I select the Distinct Values fron a column in a datatable and insert them to TreeView.

```
string[] menuGroup = ((from DataRow row1 in _ds.Tables["Rest_grdvitems"].Rows
                       orderby row1["Menu_Group"]
                   select row1["Menu_Group"].ToString()).Distinct()).ToArray();

           TreeNode node = new TreeNode("All Items");
           TV_Categories_List.Nodes.Add(node);
           foreach (string menuitem in menuGroup)
           {
               TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode(menuitem);
               TV_Categories_List.Nodes.Add(node1);
           }
```

Since I have large no of rows to be inserted to TreeView, I need to avoid Iterations.

Can you hep me??

Comment: Do you think dataseource is not using foreach?

Comment: I don't know about that? can you  explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TreeView (nor the ListView) can not be directly bound to a DataSource.

As @IamStalker states as a comment, there are iterations in the internal WinForms binding control mechanism: there is nothing wrong with iterating in your data to populate a TreeView.

If your main concern is the performance, then you should ensure you enclose the code that add nodes with `.BeginUpdate`() and `.EndUpdate()` methods: it will lock the TreeView display refresh during the populate operation. This is only applicable to the WinForms TreeView

To have only one iteration, you should change the LINQ as below (put var instead of string[] and remove .ToArray()). So the LINQ statement will returns a LINQ `IEnumerable<string>` instead of a string[]. This way, it will only be enumerated in the foreach loop that populates the TreeView.

```
var menuGroup = (from DataRow row1 in _ds.Tables["Rest_grdvitems"].Rows
                orderby row1["Menu_Group"]
                select row1["Menu_Group"].ToString()).Distinct();

TreeNode node = new TreeNode("All Items");

TV_Categories_List.BeginUpdate();

TV_Categories_List.Nodes.Add(node);
foreach (string menuitem in menuGroup)
{
    TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode(menuitem);
    TV_Categories_List.Nodes.Add(node1);
}

TV_Categories_List.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: It's hard to compare because the TreeView does not implement the usual WinForms databinding mechanism. However, as iterating a array of string is a very fast scenario, there is not too much to worry about. Please give this gode a try: applying BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate() to a TreeView really makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide me a way to place Datatable column to string array without using loops ?? the code I have is fine but I already have the Distinct values. so I directly need to put them to String array or to treeview?

Comment: Yes there is a way to remove the first LINQ loop by returning a LINQ expression instead of an Array. I edited my answer.

Comment: +1 for using an `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `ToArray().` :P